# Accessing IE8+ Compatibility Mode programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer

Is it possible to access the IE compatibility mode programmatically using ASP.Net. As my application works fine on IE 7 and 8 but fails to work on 9 and 10. Its failing because our app is using Telerik ASP.Net 2006 Controls that has lots of issues with latest IE.

Comment: http://webdesign.about.com/od/internetexplorer/qt/force-compatibility-view-in-ie.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your problem is to put the below line in the design page into the Header Tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

It will change the Document Mode to IE9.

Hope it may solve your problem.

Thank you